# Lotus Notes Authentication

Tags: lotus-notes

I want to setup Lotus Notes on my laptop to mess around with it.  I am trying to setup my email, but my email through verizon.net requires authentication.  I have it setup in Outlook 07, but Outlook does not have support for Databasing.  Does anyone know how to setup authentication for outgoing email in Lotus Notes, let alone is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In your personal address book in Lotus Notes (File > Database > Open > names.nsf), go to the Advanced > Accounts section and create a new account.  You'll need to create one count for POP and one account for SMTP to send and receive email.  There are fields in those forms where you can put the authentication info.

Answer (score 2):

Ken is correct, but I would like to counter Todd's remark (although I didn't vote you down, Todd).

Saying that Notes is crappy because it is not a RDBMS is like saying SQL is crappy because it is not a Network Operating System.  Notes is tremendously powerful at what it does - indeed, it has no rival.  Visual Studion + WinForms is in no way equivalent.  There are things you can do in either Notes or a RDBMS - sometimes one platform will be better, sometimes the other.

Enjoy, Mark.

Answer (score -1):

Ken Pespisa's answer is correct.

However, you need to understand that the nsf (Notes Databases) are completely flat files.  They are in no way relational.  Believe me, there are plenty of ways you can squeeze relational data into a notes database and everyone of them will leave you with TONS of maintanince nightmares and crappy data.

Mitch's comment to you is dead on, just mess around with SQL Server Express or MySQL.  If you want the RAD aspect of Notes, just use Visual Studio with WinForms or something.

Comment: I'll take the hit, but can someone please explain why this was voted down?

Comment: Your comment does not have anything to do with the question. It just seems to be a "let us bash Lotus Notes"- answer... There is NO truth in generally damning Lotus Notes. of course: if you try to use it as a relational database, then you will fail, as it is NOT a RDBMS. But comparing Lotus Notes with Visual Studio and WinForms is... No i won't say this. I did NOT vote you down, but it for sure was not a bad idea...

Comment: I know this is super old now, but I guess so was my comment when it was commented upon. I was not bashing Notes at all, nor did I say that Notes was crappy. I was saying if you try to make a non RDBMS into one you end up with data in a poor state (fields concatenated together with semicolons or some nonsense like that).